# Regarding storage issue for mixed-type value matrix

Tags: matlab

There has a loop in my program, and during each iteration an ID will be generated. I want to store these IDs into a two dimensional array, i.e., A. The first column of A stores the iteration number, i.e., A(1,1) = 1 and A(2,1) = 2. The second column of A stores the ID generated during each iteration, i.e., A(1,2) stores the ID generated during the first iteration. The tricky part is that these IDs can be either a numerical value or a string. For instance, A(1,2) = 12345;  A(2,2) = abcde

Which kind of data structure should I use to store this mixed-value matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two good options, a cell array or an array of structures.

1. To use a cell array you need to use braces:

   ```
   A{1,1} = 1;
   A{2,1} = 2;
   A{1,2} = 12345;
   A{2,2} = 'abcd';
   ```

   You cannot use most vectorized code with cell arrays, although you can convert numeric subsets to numeric arrays, for example:

   ```
   col1 =  cell2mat(A(:,1));
   ```
2. To use an array of structures, you need to define fields.  This has the advantage that you can name your columns of data.

   ```
   A(1).iteration = 1;
   A(2).iteration = 2;
   A(1).result = 12345;
   A(2).result = 'abcd';
   ```

   To access a single row of data, use `A(1)`, like this

   ```
   >> A(1)
   ans = 
       iteration: 1
       result: 12345
   ```

   To access a column of data, use brackets or braces

   ```
   >> [A.iteration]  %This results a numeric array, or an error if not possible
   ans =
        1     2
   >> {A.result}  %This returns a cell array, as discussed above.
   ans = 
       [12345]    'abcd'
   ```

Which option you use depends on the nature of your task and what method is more suitable to your style.  I usually start with a cell array, and eventually convert to an array of structs to take advantage of the named fields.